# Quick question on the roots and poles of a meromorphic function,

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, conformal-geometry, singularity-theory, mobius-transformation

Does the degree of the polynomial in the numerator always equal the degree of the polynomial in the denominator?

In other words, the number of zeros, counting multiplicity, equals the number of poles, counting multiplicity, of a meromorphic function.

So something like

$$\frac{z^2}{(z-1)(z+1)}$$

would be a legitimate construction of a meromorphic function

while

$$\frac{z^5}{(z-1)(z+1)}$$

is *not* a meromorphic function, since the degrees of its zeros and poles do not match.  It is simply a *rational* function.

Is my thinking correct?

Thanks,

Comment: No, both are meromorphic functions.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much @BenS. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting $\infty$. The second example has a pole of order 3 at the point at infinity.

Comment: Ah, of course.  Thanks so much for your answer, @ReneSchipperus :-)